# CSS, float left and dynamically center

Tags: css

I would like to get that effect:

[image]

In simply way i can do it like that:

```
<style>
img {
  float: left; 
  margin: auto auto;
}

.test {
}
</style>

<div class="test">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui <img src="pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" style="width:170px;height:170px;margin-right:15px;">eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit</p>
</div>
```

but in my case texts will be always dynamically and I would like to img would be always in the center.

How to do it? How to use float: left with dynamically text and centered image?

Regards,
Krzysztof.

Comment: `shape-outside` seems to fit the bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my article: https://css-tricks.com/float-an-element-to-the-bottom-corner/

You can use `shape-outside` to achieve this

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.box {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.float {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  shape-outside: inset(calc(50% - 50px) 0);
}
```

```html
<h1>Resize the below div!</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="float"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100"></div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in dui quis orci ultricies aliquet nec sed enim. Mauris id rutrum nulla, et ornare leo. Donec aliquet malesuada tellus, eu laoreet lectus tincidunt ut. Quisque lacus magna, interdum eu urna
    ac, aliquet gravida orci. Pellentesque gravida urna sit amet nulla suscipit, at venenatis lorem dignissim. Morbi quis nunc eu velit condimentum ornare. Curabitur finibus tincidunt ullamcorper. Pellentesque tincidunt et odio vitae tempus. Praesent
    ac erat ut eros venenatis pulvinar. Pellentesque eu dapibus dui. Ut semper sed enim ut vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae elit eget velit porttitor consequat nec sed turpis. Proin libero nisl, egestas
    hendrerit vulputate et, lobortis non nulla. Aenean dui libero, dictum vel nibh eget, tristique egestas enim.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play with flex, clear and calc()

Example from your code

```css
img {
  float: left; 
  margin: auto auto;
  clear:left;
}

.test {
  display:flex;
} 
.test > p:before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  border-left:red solid;/* see me and help understand what goes on here */
  height:calc((100% - 170px) / 2 );
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<p><img src="https://freesvg.org/storage/img/thumb/Food-pineapple-remix-2016021755.png" alt="Pineapple" style="width:170px;height:170px;margin-right:15px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit</p>
</div>
```

How does it work ?

a flex child has an height value even if it is not set within the style sheet .
A child or a pseudo can then receive an heightXX% that will be calculated from the flex-item parent's height.

float is out of the flow, but floatting element can clear themsleves from previous sibbling. to avoid conflicts with content around it, put first / ahead the floatting element so  that  the content that should wrap around actually does.

calc() can be used to calculate a new value. here we need , the height of the flex item, minus the height of the image (known in your case) and dividing that result by 2 gives us how much from top this image should be standing. If that result is given to a floatting pseudo, then you need to clear the floatting image from it, pushing it down.

*Position sticky could also be used to calculate top or bottom offset coordonates , shape-outside is already answered and also can com from an svg hoding your image in its vertical center ;) One question, many answers/method*